# PCA for antisymmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, principal-component-analysis

Principal Component Analysis (PCA) is often used to convert a symmetric matrix to lower-dimensional one. Is there a similiar method for antisymmetric matrices?

As we known, the eigenvalues of antisymmetric is in pairs with $+$, $-$ respectively. Could I choose the $\max | \cdot |$ pairs to do PCA?

Is there good referrence recommented?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Given a data matrix $X$, PCA can be done by eigenvalue decomposition of the **co-variance** matrix $S=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i^T$. The eigenvalue decomposition is $S=U\Lambda U$ and the representation in the lower dimension, $d$, is given by $XU_d$.

You can Conduct PCA on any data matrix, and if your data matrix happens to be anti symmetric, where $X=-X^T$, the co-variance matrix of $X$ will still be symmetric and therefore will have an eigenvalue decomposition.